# Swift Haneke: cache doesn't resolve

Tags: swift, caching, haneke

I'm trying to pre-load some images with the following code:

```
let thumbnailUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
let fetcher = NetworkFetcher<UIImage>(URL: thumbnailUrl)
Shared.imageCache.fetch(fetcher) {
    println("Finished")
}
```

But afterwards when I try to set it to the imageview, it downloads it again from the network instead of reading it from the cache. This is the code:

```
self.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(
    NSURL(string: urlString)
    success: { thumbnail in
        println("Finished setting image")
    }
)
```

Is this a bug or maybe I missunderstood the usage of `imageCache.fetch()`?

PD: I put breakpoints in the whole code, and I can guarantee the **key** for the cache (in this case, the url) is exactly the same, so I have no clue why the cache isn't resolving when used with `.hnk_setImageFromURL()`

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this for 3 days. I hope this answer might help someone else in the future.

The issue was that I didn't specify a **Format Name** to the `fetcher`, while the `UIImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL()` does. The way to fix it is:

```
let thumbnailUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
let fetcher = NetworkFetcher<UIImage>(URL: thumbnailUrl)
let cache = Shared.imageCache
let format = self.imageView.hnk_format

cache.fetch(fetcher, formatName: format.name) {
    println("Finished")
}
```

Comment: incase if any body want above code. Do not forget to add format in cache object i.e. cache.addFormat(format)